# iReport: Error connecting to JasperReports Server repository

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have error when connect *iReport* to *JR Server*'s repository. I have installed *iReport v. 5.1.0* on *Windows 8*.

The *JR Server* url, user and pass are correctly.

[image]

this is the log iReport

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:348)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.RepositorySoapBindingStub.get(RepositorySoapBindingStub.java:247)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.get(WSClient.java:280)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.get(WSClient.java:247)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ui.actions.RefreshAction$1.run(RefreshAction.java:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:240)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: You should find the full log

Comment: Is this the browser crash log or the tomcat log? You should look in the tomcat log? Is Jasper Server on your local machine or on a remote machine? If remote, it might be worth testing shutting down the firewall and trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found this link below fix my problem
http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23403071-Network-connectivity-issues-when-running-under-Java-1-7

The option file is located in `iReport-5.2.0\etc\ireport.conf`
Since I am using IPV4, I added `-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` into the `default_options` string.